# For discrete optimization problems, why does continuous approximation - solving - discretization work?

Tags: ising-model, spin-models, optimization

I was wondering about the following question.

In maths/computer science, many optimization problems ask for integer optimizations. A prominent example would be spin-glass (Ising) systems for simulated annealing (which encompasses quadratic unconstrained binary optimisation problems, such as Max-Cut etc.). Here, we have an optimisation function

and the optimization values are binary, i.e.  [image] .

Commonly, to solve this problem (e.g. with simmulated annealing, or simulated quantum annealing ; or with gradient-based methods) we approximate the values [image] as real numbers to achieve differentiability of [image] .

My question now is why this actually works / when this gives the right solution. In problems like the one mentioned above, but also for e.g. training of binary neural networks, the continuous outcome parameters will be discretized in a final step, mostly according to some threshold function [image]. Then, a common choice is to set the continuous value to +1 if it is above some treshold [image] and to -1 otherwise.

My question concerns the following: I do not see how

discrete problem --> optimization --> discrete-valued solution

gives the same optimal output as

discrete problem --> continuous relaxation --> optimization --> discretization of continuous solution --> discrete-valued solution

for a couple of reasons. Depending on the discretization function [image] we bias our real-valued answers towards some direction. For the above example of spin-glass, this seems to induce spin-flip errors. Yet, depending on the problem, nearest-neighbour flips can already lead to strongly sub-optimal solutions.

I would be happy if you could share your insight here. Specifically, (1) is such a continuous-variable relaxation generally "good", in particular for spin-glass sytems (and if yes, how good? and why?), (2) if not, when is continuous relaxation a good thing to do and (3) apart from computational convenience, what are the reasons to do the relaxations? Are there any maths papers / theorems that discuss this issue?

Best regards,
Dan